# jquery change span value by hidden attribute and value comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

My problem is i get any attribute some how.
I'm trying to print a span with different values in combination with a select/option.

I tried in the fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/dxke6fun/

```
    <div>
    <span id="display-text-"> Good Bye World! </span>
    <input type="hidden" id="objectid" secret="1" print="Hello World 1" />
    <input type="hidden" id="objectid" secret="2" print="Hello World 2" />
    <input type="hidden" id="objectid" secret="3" print="Hello World 3" />
    <input type="hidden" id="objectid" secret="4" print="Hello World 4" />
</div>

<select onchange="changeValue('objectid',this)"> 
    <option secret="1">Option 1</option>
    <option secret="2">Option 2</option>
    <option secret="3">Option 3</option>
    <option secret="4">Option 4</option>
</select>

function changeValue(id,select) {
   var secret = $(sel).attr("secret");
   var print_secret = $("hidden-" + id).attr("secret").val(secret);

            $(function(){
                $("#hidden-" + id).text(print_secret);
            });
```

Comment: please post the code inside your question also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are going to be achieve. Please go through the sample work. I hope it is useful for you. Thanks

```
<div>
    <span id="display-text-"> Good Bye World! </span>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden-001" secret="1" print="Hello World 1" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden-002" print="Hello World 2" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden-003" print="Hello World 3" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden-004" print="Hello World 4" />
</div>

<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

jquery be

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var secret = $(this).val();
    var print_secret = $("#hidden-00" + secret).attr('print');
    $("#display-text-").text(print_secret);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dxke6fun/1/)

Comment: this is a good way to the answer, but there is a second attribute

Comment: i meant something like this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/dxke6fun/2/ it should check up which secret is the same and then print the attribute 'print' in the span

Comment: @user3485007 - Sorry friend don't know

Comment: can't i select two attributes where they both are these values?

Comment: friend of mine suggested using global data attributes: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)